# Module not found using Input function from tensorflow.keras.layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Im quite new learning machine learning and my first project is the creation of a Neural Network in order to detect key facial points on google colab. Everything has been working ok but today when I wanted to train my neural network I came accross with an error that has never appeared before when I trained my neural network.

The error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-47fd3efd0229> in <module>()
      5
      6 
----> 7 X_input = Input(input_shape)
      8 
      9 # Zero-padding

4 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.base_layer_v1'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

I don't understand the line `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.base_layer_v1'` because the line that is not working is when I'm using **Input** from *tensorflow.keras.layers*.

I really don't know what is going on because I never got this error before. I've seen that it could be the version of TensorFlow or maybe my libraries.

I am using 2.3.0 versions in TensorFlow and Keras and these are the libraries I am importing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from IPython.display import display
from tensorflow.python.keras import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
```

I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Did you install the keras package?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy yeah, I installed keras 2.3.0 and tensorflow 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing tensorflow and keras works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).